# how to make my list to append different type data in python?

Tags: python

The list in python can load different type of data.

```
>>> x=[3,4,"hallo"]
>>> x
[3, 4, 'hallo']
```

How can i define a multi-dim list to load different type of data?

```
>>> info=['']*3
>>> info[0].append(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I want to make info to be a multi-dim list,info[0] can load character and number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply you are trying to append to a string that happens to be contained in a list. But you can't append to a string (string concatenation is something else). So either use string concatenation (if that was what you intended), or use an empty list as a container inside the list.

```
l = [[],[]]
```

is a list with two elements, two empty lists.

```
l.append('something')
```

gives you

```
[[],[],'something']
```

but l[0].append('something') would have given you:

```
[['something'],[]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Create an empty list of lists first:

```
info = [[] for _ in range(3)]
info[0].append(2)
info[1].append("test")
```

`info` will then look like:

```
[[2], ['test'], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `append`, do it as follows:

```
>>> info=['']*3

>>> info[0] += '2'              #if you want it stored as a string
```

#### Or

```
>>> info[0] = int(info[0]+'2')  #if you want it stored as an int
```